Hoping to get some details on the GE CF6-50 Turbine bucket thermal protective coating
I just bought this beautiful little bucket and am trying to find the details so I can describe it accurately.

Just based on the gold appearance I assumed it was TiN, but looking further it seems like more exotic coatings are more typical, although I couldn't find any clear references.
Details on the specific Nickel superalloy or other notes (holes are laser or EDM?) would be appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi there, welcome to Aviation.SE! Please read [tour], [help/on-topic], and [help/dont-ask] before posting a question. Although your title state that this is from the General Electric CF6 turbine, and thus related to aviation, not all people here will be able to determine the material of the coating. Please check out Chemistry.SE. The people there may be more suited to answer your question.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 I seriously doubt that Chemistry.SE could help here, just based on a picture. The people who know about materials used in turbine engines are more likely to be found here. And asking questions about which materials are used in aircraft engines is certainly on-topic here.
